# Get category list using wordpress query from post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get category list but my query returns all posts

```
 <?php 
    global $post;
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 24,
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'orderby' => 'title'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();
        if(get_the_id() == $thisId){$class = "active";}else{$class="";}
    ?>

    <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```

gives me all posts in output and i want to display all categories

Comment: where is your query? how do you use it?

Comment: above the $args i am passing query parameters and then execute it into query

Comment: your question is unclear, where you filter the category ,whether in mysql query? if yes then post your query string for better help

Comment: Shouldn't the $args array contain some category? Or do you want to retrieve all posts grouped by category?

Comment: No i just want to get all categories in this query ... thanks for your support.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories, https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: this is returning all posts heading, i want its category :(

Comment: I still haven't found an answer, can anyone tell me that why i got -1 for the question ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer if anyone require like i want

```
<ul>
<?php 
            global $post;
            $args = array(
                'show_option_all'    => '',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'show_count'         => 0,
                'hide_empty'         => 1,
                'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
                'child_of'           => 0,
                'feed'               => '',
                'title_li'           => '',
                'feed_type'          => '',
                'feed_image'         => '',
                'exclude'            => '',
                'exclude_tree'       => '',
                'include'            => '',
                'hierarchical'       => 1,
                'echo'               => 1,
                'taxonomy'           => 'category'
            );
            $the_query = wp_list_categories( $args ); 

            ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found simple method to show the categories.

wordpress have inbuilt function `wp_list_catergories()`

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
    'style'      => 'list',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    );
    wp_list_categories($args); 
?>
```

this will automatically render the categories with link, no need to write loop and all.

if you want to have all the props of the catogories, use `get_categories()`

```
 <?php 
    $args = array(
    'style'      => 'list',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    );
    get_categories($args); 
?>
```

ref: https://phppot.com/wordpress/how-to-get-wordpress-categories/